# Creating a folder in the root of the filesystem results in "Operation not permitted"

Tags: macos, high-sierra, permission, sip

The following command:

`$ sudo mkdir /AppleInternal`
and entering my password when prompted,

results in:
`mkdir: /AppleInternal: Operation not permitted`

Is this because of System Integrity Protection? I'm sure I've done this previously with no issues. I'm on High Sierra (10.13.4).

btw, the reason I want to create that folder is so I can run the iOS Simulator in split screen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46887389/368085

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of SIP, but only with the name ‘AppleInternal’. You can create other folders and files in the root, but the name AppleInternal is restricted. You can neither create a folder with the name AppleInternal, nor create a folder with a different name and rename it AppleInternal.

Comment: Damn! That is sneaky  We just want to have nice things Apple 